# Как правильно высчитать угол у 2 точек на карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, математика

Есть координаты 2 точек на карте ([x1, y1], [x2, y2])
Получены так `Polygon.geometry.getCoordinates()`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Зеленой стрелкой показана прямая и из её двух точек получен угол в 63 градуса, хотя на глаз там должно быть около 45 градусов.

Подскажите как мне верно рассчитать угол?

```
    var c = myPolygon.geometry.getCoordinates();

    var pointOne = c[0].reverse();
    var pointTwo = c[1].reverse();

    var offset = {
      x: pointTwo[0] - pointOne[0],
      y: pointTwo[1] - pointOne[1]
    };

    var angle = Math.atan2(offset.y, -(offset.x)) * (180 / Math.PI) - 90;
    angle = angle < 0 ? angle + 360 : angle;
    angle = angle % 360;

    console.log(angle);
```

Comment: не понятно совсем, про какие точки и угол идет речь

Comment: Неочевидно, о каком именно угле речь, но если судить по скриншоту на глаз, то угол между вертикалью и зеленой стрелкой составляет как раз около 60 градусов.

Comment: Есть точка A возьмем её за начало координат 0, 0 допустим.
Вторая точка B лежит на воображаемой окружности ) 
И надо найти угол https://prnt.sc/mzi6u1

Comment: И фишка в том что я получаю координаты по которым градус угла не совсем верный

Comment: Покажите значения координат. По двум точкам угол найти нельзя, угол задаётся тремя точками. Вот азимут - можно.

Answer (score 1):

Если я Вас правильно понял вы ищите азимут.

Эта функция, про которую вы спрашиваете, вы ее уже использовали [`Math.atan2(y, x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2), только она возвращает результат относительно оси абсцисс и против часовой стрелки, если говорить про угол на карте это скорее всего азимут и он откладывается от направления на север и по часовой стрелке; Для преобразования к этому углу необходимо то что вернул atan2 вычесть из направления на север (90 градусов относительно оси абсцисс или PI/2) и потом получившийся угол привести к положительному, если он отрицательный, т.к. отрицательный азимут особо не используется

```js
azimuth(0, 0,  1,  1)
azimuth(0, 0,  1, -1)
azimuth(0, 0, -1, -1)
azimuth(0, 0, -1,  1)

function azimuth(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
  let a = 90 - Math.atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1)*180/Math.PI;
  if (a<0) a += 360;
  console.log(a)
}
```

——-

Однако, это справедливо для плоскости, а карта - это проекция геоида на плоскость

Если Вам нужна **математика на геоиде для javascript**, рекомендую воспользоваться
[turf.js](http://turfjs.org/).

——

По поводу проекций:

Все существующие картографические проекции могут быть подразделены на классы по характеру искажений

——-

[image: Равноугольная проекция]

**Равноугольные проекции**. На этих проекциях углы не искажаются, т. е. углы на местности между какими-либо направлениями равны углам на карте между теми же направлениями.

Бесконечно малые фигуры на карте в силу свойства равноугольности будут подобны тем же фигурам на Земле.

Если остров круглой формы в природе, то и на кар- те в равноугольной проекции он изобразится кружком некоторого радиуса.

Но линейные же размеры на картах этой проекции будут искажены.

——-

[image: Проекция Альберса]

[image: Равновеликая азимутальная проекция Ламберта]

**Равновеликие проекции**. На этих проекциях сохраняется пропорциональность площадей фигур, т. е. если площадь какого-либо участка на Земле в два раза больше другого, то на проекции изображение первого участка по площади тоже будет в два раза больше изображения второго.

Однако в равновеликой проекции не сохраняется подобие фигур.

Остров круглой формы будет изображен на проекции в виде равновеликого ему эллипса.

——-

**Произвольные проекции**.

Эти проекции не сохраняют ни подобия фигур, ни равенства площадей, но могут иметь какие-нибудь другие специальные свойства, необходимые для решения на них определенных практических задач.

Наибольшее применение в судовождении из карт произвольных проекций получили ортодромические, на которых ортодромии (большие круги шара) изображаются прямыми линиями, а это очень важно при использовании некоторых радионавигационных систем при плавании по дуге большого круга.

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема в другом, формула работает которую я в задаче описал, но координаты из API яндекса я получаю кривые, то есть на глаз видно что угол около 45 градусов должен быть, а получаю 63 из полученных координат

Comment: так это, вы на сфере гляньте, карта же это проекция, по ней нельзя судить об углах

Comment: Тогда может есть более простой и точный вариант получить точку повернутую на определенный градус (То есть мне надо задать начальные координаты точки и иметь возможность вращать её, чтобы потом отобразить некое изображение повернутое на этот угол)? 
В апи я такого решения не нашел и пришлось лепить из 2 точек, чтобы потом вычислять угол

Comment: @ИванГрозный вам нужна математика на геоиде?

Comment: @ИванГрозный вероятно http://turfjs.org/ вот тут есть то, что вы ищите

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я не могу правильно сформулировать свою мысль ) 
Я просто буду делать задачу немного иначе, не касаясь координат карты.

Comment: @ИванГрозный объясните исходную задачу, если можно

Comment: Мне на карте надо показать нечто такое http://prntscr.com/mzo56l
То есть нужна начальная точка и градус куда поворачивать изображение (Это как бы показывает куда смотрит окно из квартиры, ну или камера на доме куда смотрит), чтобы такое сделать, я в админке хотел дать возможность ставить 1 точку как начальную и 2-ю куда будет смотреть изображение, тем самым по формуле прогонял 2 точки и получал желаемый градус, но градус барахлит и показывает неверно, на этом изображении это не видно, но на других явно виден сдвиг.

Comment: Поэтому я решил ставить полигон Circle и сразу вписывать туда изображение и путем не хитрых манипуляций меняю градус картинки внутри полигона через input, так я избавился от формул с координатами карты, может кому пригодится такое решение )

Comment: @ИванГрозный ну если вращать карту не надо то никаких проблем не должно быть